# How can I enable termination protection for an EC2 Instance managed by the CDK, and still allow the CDK to terminate it in order to replace it?

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

We have had a PEN test requirement to enable termination protection on all our EC2 instances.

We have bastion instances managed by the CDK. We fulfilled this requirement as so:

```java
var bastion = BastionHostLinux.Builder.create(...).build();
var cfnBastion = (CfnInstance) bastion.getNode().getDefaultChild().getNode().getDefaultChild();
cfnBastion.setDisableApiTermination(true);
```

However, now whenever a new kernel is released the CDK / CloudFormation provisions a new bastion instance, and then tries and fails to terminate the old one - because it has termination protection enabled.

Is there any hook that will let the CDK disable termination protection when it wants to decommission an instance it is managing?

Comment: Same question on re:Post: https://repost.aws/questions/QU-lG74iSHTK-m3R2suxxHeg/how-can-i-enable-termination-protection-for-an-ec2-instance-managed-by-the-cdk-and-still-allow-the-cdk-to-terminate-it-in-order-to-replace-it

Answer (score 0):

Use `AwsCustomResource` with `onDelete` to call SDK for remove the termination protection.
It's similar to we must empty S3 bucket before deleting it